# JavaScript Closest point from mouse

Tags: javascript, arrays, mouse, distance, closest

Before you comment, yes i have checked other questions aswell...
like [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791010/how-to-find-the-coordinate-that-is-closest-to-the-point-of-origin), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170392/find-closest-point-to-mouse-position), or maybe even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048526/closest-point-of-a-set-to-a-given-point). However, i couldn't find how to set the point of origin. So, let's say i have an array picture X coords and picture Y coords

(on a grid of 100*100)
x /y
92/81
82/47
81/03

Now i have the mouseX and mouseY.
Does anyone know how to make a function that gives you the closest point x and y values in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do some vecor math. Given the images and the touch position:

```
 const coords = [[92, 81],  [82, 47], [81, 03]];
 const touchX = 57, touchY = 84;
```

Just go over them and calculate the distance vecors length:

```
let closest = [null, null];
let distance = Infinity;

for(const [x, y] of coords){
  let d = Math.sqrt((touchX - x) ** 2 + (touchY - y) ** 2);
  if(d < distance){
    closest = [x, y];
    distance = d;
  }
}
```

[Vectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector)

[Calculating the length](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)