# Dofus nearest portal

Tags: javascript

> Hi, I'm here to ask you how to calculate coordinates in JavaScript.
>   I am a player on the Dofus game and in Dofus there are coordinates.

`Right > + 1`,
`Left > - 1`,
`Top > - 1`,
`Bottom > + 1`

It's the coordinates in this game.
In Dofus there are Zaap (Fixed teleport portals in the world that are at positions that do not change ex:`[-20;-20]`). I would like to know according to the coordinates given by the user for example `[-6;11]`, which Zaap is nearest to this position.

If it can be a function of style:
`function getNearestPortal(myposition){};`
That would be really cool.

Interactive map: https://dofus-map.com/

Position of the portals:

```
[-5,8]
[3,-5]
[5,7]
[-2,0]
[-1,24]
[7,4]
[4,-19]
[10,22]
[13,26]
[13,35]
[-32,-56]
[-26,35]
[35,12]
[27,-14]
[25,-4]
[-24,12]
[-16,1]
[17,-31]
[23,-22]
[29,49]
[26,-37]
[30,-38]
[-13,-28]
[-5,-23]
[-14,-47]
[-20,-20]
[1,-32]
[-34,-8]
[-18,-26]
[-53,18]
[-46,18]
[-54,16]
[-67,-75]
[-78,-41]
[-77,-73]
```

If you need more information, ask me.

It's a complex request more than the game is not played by many people :/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, but you have to explain the game, so that you can understand, and besides I'm not English so it's 2 difficulties, you see?
But I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that i have adapted from [this S.O. Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199265/9070080) to suit your needs:

Note: This assumes your coordinates are stored in a nested array, feel free to let me know if this will not suit your needs

```
//Store all coordinates in a 2D array
let coords = [[-5,8],[3,-5],[5,7],[-2,0],[-1,24],[7,4],[4,-19],[10,22],[13,26],[13,35],[-32,-56],[-26,35],[35,12],[27,-14],[25,-4],[-24,12],[-16,1],[17,-31],[23,-22],[29,49],[26,-37],[30,-38],[-13,-28],[-5,-23],[-14,-47],[-20,-20],[1,-32],[-34,-8],[-18,-26],[-53,18],[-46,18],[-54,16],[-67,-75],[-78,-41],[-77,-73]];

//myposition is an array of length 2 in the form of [x, y]
function getNearestPortal(myposition){

  closest = [null, null];
  let distance = Infinity;

  //Loop through coords and check if the current position is closest to the given point
  for(const [x, y] of coords){
    let d = Math.sqrt((myposition[0] - x) ** 2 + (myposition[1] - y) ** 2);
    if(d < distance){
      closest = [x, y];
      distance = d;
    }
  }

  return closest;
};

getNearestPortal([15, 20]);
//[10, 22]
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I thank you very much, I have been looking for several hours how to do this...